# Hide ComboBox Item

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, itemtemplate

I am using a ComboBox filled with some Userlevels:

[image: full list]

I also use a Converter which checks if a Userlevel is visible or not.
Converter is working fine. But the items are still in the list, they are empty only:

[image: filtered list]

I use a TextBlock inside the Combobox to show the text. 
Here is my code:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="UserlevelComboBox" Width="300" Height="50"
               ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UserlevelList}"
               SelectedValue="{Binding Userlevel.Id}"
               SelectedValuePath="Id"
               SelectedItem="{Binding Userlevel}"
               IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}">
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Userlevel, Converter={StaticResource userlevelConverter}}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Is it possible to get the Combobox Items look like this:

[image]

Thanks a lot. best regards Phil

Comment: apply your DataTrigger in ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle. at the moment you are hiding only TextBlocks. ComboBoxItems are still Visible

Comment: Why you do not provide filtered list in VeiwModel? Then you could just bind to this list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment you are hiding only TextBlocks. But in ComboBox items are wrapped in container items - ComboBoxItem - which are still Visible.

Apply your DataTrigger in ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle.:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="UserlevelComboBox" Width="300" Height="50"
               ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UserlevelList}"
               SelectedValue="{Binding Userlevel.Id}"
               SelectedValuePath="Id"
               SelectedItem="{Binding Userlevel}"
               IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Userlevel, Converter={StaticResource userlevelConverter}}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Tried to disable default/selected item? By me it doesn't appear in dropdown, but still present in text field.

Comment: thanks, this is working. I've just added an ItemTemplate for showing the Text too:                                                                  <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

Comment: @Phil, wpf creates TextBlocks to display any text. So ComboBox will create TextBlocks to display text inside ComboBoxItems. I didn't notice `{Binding Text}` part, sorry. It changes the display. As an alternative to ItemTemplate set DisplayMemberPath: `<ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Text" ...>`

Comment: @ASh: yes, you're right. You can use DisplayMemberPath too.